# Influx Connection fails with: '401: "error":"authorization failed"

Tags: linux, yaml, influxdb

I would like to use an existing (external) Influx instance as a sensor in HA.
I have the following setup:

**Server 1:** Homeassistant OS installed

- Core 2024.1.3
- Supervisor 2023.12.0
- Operating System 11.4
- Frontend 20240104.0
- The "InfluxDB" plugin is installed, which also allows me to connect to the Influx instance of Sever2 and create queries.

**Server 2**: Influx instance

- version 1.8.10
- IP: 192.168.28.77
- database "monitoring"
- user name and password are assigned.
- SSL is not used

I would like to use data from Server2 as a sensor.
Here is my **config.yaml**

```
influxdb:
  exclude:
    entity_globs: “*”
```

And here **sensors.yaml**

```
- platform: influxdb
  host: 192.168.28.77
  port: 8086
  database: monitoring
  username: config
  password: "myPassword"
  ssl: false
  api_version: 1
  queries:
    - name: zimmertemperatur_bad
      unit_of_measurement: °C
      value_template: "{{ temperature_C | round(1) }}"
      #where: 'time > now() - 7d'
      where: 'time = now()'
      measurement: '"monitoring"."autogen"."LaCrosse-TX141THBv2"'
      field: "temperature_C"
      group_function: last
      database: monitoring
```

But I get the following error:

`[homeassistant.components.influxdb] InfluxDB database is not accessible due to '401: {"error":"authorization failed"}'. Please check that the database, username and password are correct and that the specified user has the correct permissions set. Retrying in 60 seconds.`

Why can't Homeassistant query any values via the YAML configuration?

It can't be a user restriction because the Influx plugin from Homeassistant connects to Server2 without any problems.